# How to force download PDF from folder to browser / user by JavaScript or Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, axios

**HTML (ejs template) code:**

```
<input class="download" data-orderId="<%= orders[i].stubhubOrderId %>" type="button" value="Download">
```

**JavaScript / jQuery code:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.download', function (e) {
    showSpinner();
    const orderId = $(this).attr('data-orderId');
    axios.post('/get-order-ticket-by-orderid', {
        orderId: orderId
    })
    .then(function (response) {
            hideSpinner();
            // PDF Download code
            const fileURL = '/uploads/539038653.pdf'
            const fileName = '539038653.pdf'
            // for non-IE
            if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
                var save = document.createElement('a');
                save.href = fileURL;
                save.target = '_blank';
                save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

                var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                    'view': window,
                    'bubbles': true,
                    'cancelable': false
                });
                save.dispatchEvent(evt);

                (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
            }

            // for IE < 11
            else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
                var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
                _window.document.close();
                _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
                _window.close();
            }   
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        hideSpinner();
    });
});
```

When I'm manually open PDF (http://localhost:3001/uploads/539038653.pdf) in new tab then it's working fine but by above code I'm getting corrupted / damaged file (PDF). I got this message 'PDF document is damaged' while open downloaded PDF.

Can anyone please help me download PDF file from folder by JavaScript ?

Comment: You didn't use `createObjectURL` so you should not be using `revokeObjectURL`

Comment: @Phil Didn't get you. Can you please give an example.

Comment: Sure... delete this line ~ `(window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);`

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: @Phil Tried it and same issue.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a solution. All I'm saying is that because you have not used [`createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) anywhere in your code, you should not be using `revokeObjectURL()`

Comment: @Phil Okay, got you. Can you please give an example so I can refer and I can resolve my issue ?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Example of how to download file (PDF) from folder using JavaScript.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code. Have you tried opening the downloaded PDF files with a plain text editor? Perhaps they're not PDFs

Comment: Yes I've open downloaded file in text editor and it seems encoded string i.e: %PDF-1.5
%\E2\E3\CF\D3
40 0 obj

Comment: That looks correct. Not sure what else to tell you. Does it work if you remove the `download` property from the link you create?

Comment: No not worked with that also.

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with your JavaScript code

Comment: Okay, when I'm placed PDF download code before axois call then it's working fine but  I'm creating file (PDF) by axios call when response come back (in .then) so I want that PDF file in .then().

Comment: Maybe you're too fast. What creates the PDF? Is it asynchronous, ie the HTTP response comes back before the PDF is created fully?

Comment: @Phil, I've solved my issue. I've added answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this issue by adding below code in node route '/get-order-ticket-by-orderid' (refer code in my question for '/get-order-ticket-by-orderid')

```
let wstream = data.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('uploads/test.pdf'));
 wstream.on('finish', function () {
    return res.status(data.status).json(data);
 });
```